# R call different variables dynamically

Tags: r, for-loop

I am looking for a way to call different variables dynamically.

Like, if I've got variables a1, a2, and a3 in a for loop, and I want to use a different one each time. 
Something like:

```
a1 = "Good Morning"
a2 = "Good Afternoon"
a3 = "Good Night"

for (i in 1:3){
paste("a" & i)
}
```

That paste line doesn't work, and that's what I'm looking for. A way to combine "a" and i so it reads as the variable a1, then a2, then a3.

Comment: Use vectors or lists, not sequentially named variables. You don't have data frames, but my answer at [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) applies.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `mget` and return a `list` of object values

```
mget(paste0("a", 1:3))
```

If we want to apply three different functions, use `Map/mapply`

```
Map(function(f1, x) f1(x), list(fun1, fun2, fun3),  mget(paste0("a", 1:3)))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you also happen to know of a way to do this with functions? Like, say a1, a2, and a3 were three different functions? How could I do this in that case?

Comment: @AnthonyH. Updated the post

Answer (score 4):

Yet another answer with `mget`, but determining the `"a"` variables that exist in the `.GlobalEnv` with `ls()`.

```
a_vars <- ls(pattern = "^a")
mget(a_vars)
#$a1
#[1] "Good Morning"
#
#$a2
#[1] "Good Afternoon"
#
#$a3
#[1] "Good Night"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get() to evaluate it as follows;

```
a1 = "Good Morning"
a2 = "Good Afternoon"
a3 = "Good Night"

for (i in 1:3){
  print(get(paste0("a",  i)))
}

# [1] "Good Morning"
# [1] "Good Afternoon"
# [1] "Good Night"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you also happen to know of a way to do this with functions? Like, say a1, a2, and a3 were three different functions? How could I do this in that case?

Comment: So in the loop it will be eval(call(paste0("a",  i)))